# How do I change the size of a group in the Ribbon Designer?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, ms-office, ribbon

I'm designing a ribbon in Visual Studio 2010 and I have reached a problem, that I really don't get.

As the title says, how do I change the size of a group? There are no visual way to change the default size and it seems to auto-size when being used instead.

My main problem is that I want to position the button labeled "test" to the right of the edit box, but they keep on getting on top of eachother.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but you cannot manually change the size of Ribbon groups, ribbons groups will always adjust to a specific size based on content inside them, this is outlined in the Ribbon guidelines document by Microsoft which you can view [here](http://officeblogs.net/UI/Preview%202007%20Microsoft%20Office%20System%20UI%20Design%20Guidelines.pdf).

If you want that button to appear on the right side of the group then you will have to populate the groups with either 1 large button or 3 small buttons before it will let you onto the right side of the group container.